# Add 1 to all numerical values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to increase the value of all the numbers in a table similar to the one below. Is there any way to do this in R? I am aware this is a very simple task in python.

```
if(!require(tidyverse)){install.packages("tidyverse");library('tidyverse')}

Gene = sprintf("Gene_%s", rep(10:39))
Cell = sprintf("Cell_%s", rep(10:19))

mat <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 10, nrow = 30)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
colnames(df) <- Cell
row.names(df) <- Gene
df <- rownames_to_column(df,var = "Gene")
df
```

I have tried `df + 1` and get an error:

```
Error in FUN(left, right): non-numeric argument to binary operator
Traceback:

1. Ops.data.frame(df, 1)
2. eval(f)
3. eval(f)
```

My desired output is something like this...

```
example <- df$Cell_10 + 1
example
```

However I need to do this for the whole dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first column is `character`.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Gene   : chr  "Gene_10" "Gene_11" "Gene_12" "Gene_13" ...
 $ Cell_10: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_11: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_12: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_13: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_14: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_15: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_16: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_17: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_18: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ Cell_19: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
```

So, exclude that while adding

```
df[-1] <- df[-1] + 1
```

Or programmatically find the index of numeric columns

```
i1 <- which(sapply(df, is.numeric))
df[i1] <- df[i1] + 1
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can check the column type while adding

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x + 1))
```